# Why is rxjs not passing my Observable.throw to subscribers?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code in a service which creates an observable from a Http request.

```
  const httpObservable = this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(request))
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error, caught) => {
      console.log('There was an API error for ' + url);
      console.log('Rethrowing');
      return Observable.throw(error);
    });
  return httpObservable;
```

There is no server available at the specified url and the `catch` block is being executed. As you can see the `catch` handler returns an `Observable.throw(error)` which should (as far as I understand) be caught in the next block that uses the above function.

```
const request = new Api.ThemeInfoGetQuery();
console.log('Sending request');
this.response = this.apiService.request(Api.ThemeInfoGetQuery.url, request);
console.log('Setting catch');
this.response.catch((err: any, caught: Observable<Api.ThemeInfoGetResponse>) => {
  console.log('The rethrown error was detected');
  return Observable.throw(err);
});
this.response.subscribe(x => {
  console.log('There was no error');
});
```

This is the output I expect to see in the console.

1. Sending request
2. Setting catch
3. There was an API error
4. Rethrowing
5. The rethrown error was detected

But I am only seeing up to step 4. Can anyone suggest what I might try to ensure the subscriber's `.catch` is also executed?

```
Sending request
load-theme.resolver.ts:31 Setting catch
zone.js:2177 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/api/theme/get-theme net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2177
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:384
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:274
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:378
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:209
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:232
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2201
send @ VM5471:3
(anonymous) @ http.es5.js?9c1c:1275
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:171
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:159
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/do.js.DoOperator.call @ do.js?d062:63
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/delay.js.DelayOperator.call @ delay.js?1cee:63
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/catch.js.CatchOperator.call @ catch.js?0239:79
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/finally.js.FinallyOperator.call @ finally.js?667f:26
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/tru-control/resolvers/load-theme.resolver.ts.LoadThemeResolver.resolveBrand @ load-theme.resolver.ts:37
LoadThemeResolver @ load-theme.resolver.ts:19
_createClass @ core.es5.js:9518
_createProviderInstance$1 @ core.es5.js:9486
resolveNgModuleDep @ core.es5.js:9471
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get @ core.es5.js:10557
webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.getToken @ router.es5.js?1fca:4566
webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.getResolver @ router.es5.js?1fca:4554
webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.resolveNode @ router.es5.js?1fca:4534
webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.PreActivation.runResolve @ router.es5.js?1fca:4515
(anonymous) @ router.es5.js?1fca:4282
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:120
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:110
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable.js.ArrayObservable._subscribe @ ArrayObservable.js:114
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:171
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:159
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:85
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/reduce.js.ReduceOperator.call @ reduce.js?4c7d:74
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:22
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:130
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:127
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:110
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:143
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js:23
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:143
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js:23
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/every.js.EverySubscriber.notifyComplete @ every.js?5a03:53
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/every.js.EverySubscriber._complete @ every.js?5a03:70
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._complete @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:135
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable.js.ArrayObservable._subscribe @ ArrayObservable.js:116
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:171
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:159
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:85
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/every.js.EveryOperator.call @ every.js?5a03:33
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:22
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:130
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:127
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:110
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/every.js.EverySubscriber.notifyComplete @ every.js?5a03:53
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/every.js.EverySubscriber._complete @ every.js?5a03:70
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._complete @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:135
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable.js.ArrayObservable._subscribe @ ArrayObservable.js:116
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:171
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:159
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:85
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/every.js.EveryOperator.call @ every.js?5a03:33
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:85
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:22
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:130
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:127
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:110
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:143
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js:23
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/observable/ScalarObservable.js.ScalarObservable._subscribe @ ScalarObservable.js:49
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:171
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:159
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:22
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:130
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:127
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:110
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:143
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next @ InnerSubscriber.js:23
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/observable/ScalarObservable.js.ScalarObservable._subscribe @ ScalarObservable.js:49
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:171
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:159
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:22
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:130
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:127
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:110
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next @ map.js:83
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/last.js.LastSubscriber._complete @ last.js?576b:110
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeAll.js.MergeAllSubscriber._complete @ mergeAll.js:94
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete @ Subscriber.js:114
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/observable/ScalarObservable.js.ScalarObservable._subscribe @ ScalarObservable.js:51
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:171
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:159
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeAll.js.MergeAllOperator.call @ mergeAll.js:63
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/last.js.LastOperator.call @ last.js?576b:39
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/catch.js.CatchOperator.call @ catch.js?0239:79
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:85
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:85
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:85
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:85
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js?a3bf:85
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:54
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:156
(anonymous) @ Observable.js:203
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:776
webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.forEach @ Observable.js:199
(anonymous) @ router.es5.js?1fca:4148
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:776
webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.Router.runNavigate @ router.es5.js?1fca:4073
(anonymous) @ router.es5.js?1fca:4040
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:365
onInvoke @ core.es5.js:3890
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:364
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:125
(anonymous) @ zone.js:760
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:398
onInvokeTask @ core.es5.js:3881
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:397
webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:165
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:593
api.service.ts?c446:92 There was an API error for http://localhost:5000/api/theme/get-theme
api.service.ts?c446:100 Rethrowing
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…}headers: Headersok: falsestatus: 0statusText: ""type: 3url: null_body: ProgressEventbubbles: falsecancelBubble: falsecancelable: falsecomposed: falsecurrentTarget: XMLHttpRequestdefaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 0isTrusted: truelengthComputable: falseloaded: 0path: Array(0)returnValue: truesrcElement: XMLHttpRequesttarget: XMLHttpRequesttimeStamp: 5433.305total: 0type: "error"__proto__: ProgressEvent__proto__: Body
```

Comment: iirc you can just throw a normal error like: `throw new Error()` and rxjs will handle it within the observable, can't test it right now though

Comment: Where do you expect the rethrown error to be detected?

Answer (score 1):

[`catch`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch) is an RxJS operator and as such it returns an observable - which you are ignoring. It's the returned observable that has the `catch` applied, not the observable upon which `catch` is called.

For your `catch` to have an effect, you'd need to use the returned observable, like this:

```ts
this.response = this.response.catch((err, caught) => {
  console.log('The rethrown error was detected');
  return Observable.throw(err);
});
```

Comment: Nope. Your code ignores the observable returned by the `catch` operator and it's the returned observable that has the `catch` applied to it. You need to subscribe to the returned observable for the `catch` to be composed in. Usually, you chain the operators, but as you have logging sprinkled throughout, you can just reassign to `this.response` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a new error within the catch:

```js
.catch(err => {
    this.error = "Error: " + err.status
    throw new Error('Got a 404')
})
```

and this will pass it on down the stream which can then be caught again:

```js
.subscribe(
  result => console.log(result),
  err => {
    console.log('subscribe error')
  });
```

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/g9EeF9XKrA8rpi1G6ZKE?p=preview)

You can also do it with `Observable.throw()` similar to how you have in your question

```
.catch(err => {
  console.log('Error: ', err)
  return Observable.throw('new error')
})
.subscribe(
  result => console.log(result));
```

As @cartant mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512755/6894075): You are not using the observable that is returned, another option instead of assigning the response to the result of the `.catch` is to subscribe directly to the result as shown above.

[Updated plunker with both methods](https://plnkr.co/edit/jq1c5BOwQfROzxEpkJ3L?p=preview).

Comment: That works, but why doesn't the `catch` also work on the subscribing stream?

Comment: When I subscribe I can pass a 2nd function that is called when the underlying stream throws an error. What I want to know is, shouldn't I also be able to use .`catch` on the child stream and it should also be called rather than me having to pass the 2nd function in subscribe.

Comment: Hmm, with further testing the `Observable.throw()` pattern also works: you can see it in [this updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jq1c5BOwQfROzxEpkJ3L?p=preview) is this what you are looking for? I'll update my answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

```
this.response.subscribe(
  x => {
    console.log('There was no error');
  }
  err => {
    console.log('There was error', err);
  }
);
```